# How to get Task<SearchResult<ProviderShortInfoDTO>> to SearchResult<ProviderShortInfoDTO> in c#

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-web-api

```
Dictionary<TenantDTO, Task<SearchResult<ProviderShortInfoDTO>>> tasks =
               providerIds.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => _providerManagementService.GetProviderAccounts(y.Key, GetQueryByProviders(y.Value)));

// SearchResult<ProviderShortInfoDTO>[] providerShortInfos = await Task.WhenAll(tasks.Select(x => x.Value));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep them as dictionary you can await the dictionary values and then create a new one using `Task.Result`:

```
Dictionary<TenantDTO, Task<SearchResult<ProviderShortInfoDTO>>> tasks = ...
await Task.WhenAll(tasks.Values);
var result = tasks
    .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value.Result);
```

Comment: this does not work

Comment: @ravipatel how **exactly** this does not work?

Comment: i wan to build commented line that i am  getting error

Comment: do you need SearchResult type

Comment: @ravipatel what is the exact problem? Are you getting compilation error? Runtime error?

Comment: "Response status code does not indicate success: 405 (Method Not Allowed)."

Comment: @ravipatel this means that `_providerManagementService.GetProviderAccounts(y.Key, GetQueryByProviders(y.Value))` is faulty and the problem with high chance has nothing to do with code in question.

Comment: ya you right it has issue in that provider